# Простое динамичное переключение элементов

Tags: jquery

```css
.element.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
    <!- переход на след. страницу -> 
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <!- переход на след. страницу ->
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 7 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 8 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 9 (страница2)</li>
    <!- переход на след. страницу ->
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 10 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 11 (страница3)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Предыдущая страница</button>
  <button id="next">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```

Как реализовать динамичное переключение элементов по "страницам", кол-во элементов может быть абсолютно любое.

Comment: а в чем разница с предыдущим вопросом то?

Comment: Другая структура, более простая чтоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsh3j1yj/)

Скрипт:

```js
var currPage = 0;
const pageSize = 3;
$('.element').slice(0, pageSize).show();
const maxPage = Math.floor($('.element').length / pageSize);
$("#prev").click(function() {
  if (currPage === 0) return;
  $('.element').slice(currPage * pageSize, (currPage + 1) * pageSize).hide();
  $('.element').slice(--currPage * pageSize, (currPage + 1) * pageSize).show();
});
$("#next").click(function() {
  if (currPage == maxPage) return;
  $('.element').slice(currPage * pageSize, ++currPage * pageSize).hide();
  $('.element').slice(currPage * pageSize, (currPage + 1) * pageSize).show();
});
```

```css
.element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 7 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 8 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 9 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 10 (страница4)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 11 (страница4)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Предыдущая страница</button>
  <button id="next">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно решение без p1,p2,p3 и тд. Тк с сервера элементы приходят в массиве, и после выводятся на страницу.

Comment: @kiLLro какой в таком случае конкретный обязательно присутствующий признак принадлежности элемента к той или иной странице?

Comment: по идее там ничего кроме класса element - нет. На странице максимально может быть 25 элементов, после идет переход на следующую страницу

Comment: @kiLLro ну тогда все даже проще, дополню ответ

Comment: @kiLLro обновил ответ

Answer (score -1):

```js
function pages(el, step) {
    let visible = [];
    step--;

    for (let i = 0, l = el.children.length; i < l; i++) {
        let e = el.children[i];
        i > step ? e.style.display = "none" : visible.push(e)
    }

    Object.assign(el.__proto__, {

        browse: function(route) {

            let dir = route ? "nextElementSibling" : "previousElementSibling",
                where = route ? "push" : "unshift",
                element = visible[route ? visible.length-1 : 0];

            if (!element[dir]) { return false }

            this.reset();

            for (let i = 0; i <= step; i++) {
                element = element[dir];
                if (element) {
                    visible[where](element);
                    element.style.display = "";
                }
            }

            return visible[route ? visible.length-1 : 0][dir] ? true : false

        },

        next: function() { return this.browse(1) },

        prev: function() { return this.browse() },

        reset: () => {
            let el;
            while (el = visible.shift()) {
                el.style.display = "none"
            }
        }

    });
}

let page = {
    next: document.querySelector("#next"),
    prev: document.querySelector("#prev"),
    list: document.querySelector("#list"),
    switch: (status, dir) => {
        let route = dir ? "next" : "prev";
        page[!dir ? "next" : "prev"].disabled = false;
        page[route].disabled = page.list[route]() ? false : true
    }
}

pages(page.list, 3);

page.prev.addEventListener("click", ()=>page.switch(page.list.prev));

page.next.addEventListener("click", ()=>page.switch(page.list.next,1));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
    <!--переход на след. страницу-->
    <li class="element">Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <!--переход на след. страницу-->
    <li class="element">Я элемент 7 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 8 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 9 (страница3)</li>
    <!--переход на след. страницу-->
    <li class="element">Я элемент 10 (страница4)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 11 (страница4)</li>
</ul>

<div class="buttons">
    <button id="prev" disabled="true">Предыдущая страница</button>
    <button id="next">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```